# I want to reuse part of providers list across multiple Angular Unit Tests

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing

I am fairly new to Angular/Typescript. And since I am starting a new application I am also diving into the Unit testing of Components and Services. Most of my components are using DI for services. When testing these components I not only need to provide a mock service for say example my UserService but also provide classes for all the dependencies the UserService uses. I have got this working but I am reusing a list opf providers across multiple Unit Test files. As A programmer I do not like this and would like to reuse (part) of this list though say a constant.

The code below is what I use,. My issue is concerning the providers:[]. Most of these are needed for each spec.ts except for a few services.

```
describe('HeaderMenuComponent', () => {
  let component: HeaderMenuComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<HeaderMenuComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [HeaderMenuComponent],
      imports: [
        CookieModule.forRoot(),
        HttpClientModule,
        HttpModule,
        RouterTestingModule
      ],
      providers: [CookieService, CookieModule, CookieOptionsProvider, BaseService, AuthenticationService,
        { provide: XHRBackend, useClass: MockBackend },
        { provide: ConfigurationService, useClass: ConfigurationMockService },
        { provide: UserService, useClass: UserMockService },
        {
          // Here we request that configuration loading be done at app-
          // initialization time (prior to rendering)
          provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
          useFactory: (configService: ConfigurationService) =>
            () => configService.loadConfigurationData(),
          deps: [ConfigurationService],
          multi: true
        },
        { provide: 'BASE_URL', useFactory: '', deps: [] }]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));
```

I would like the code to look something like, where DefaultProvidersList contains providers reused throughout multiple tests and Service 1 and 2 specific for current file.:

```
providers: [DefaultProvidersList, Service1, Service2]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a way to accomplish the above. Not sure if it is correct in code style but it get's the job done.

I created a file called unittest.ext.ts and a class in it and two functions, getImports() and getProviders. See below, hope it helps someone. If anyone has a better idea let me know.

```
export const UnitTestExtensions = {
  hasClass: function (element, cls) {
    var classes = element.getAttribute('class');
    var split = classes.split(' ');
    return split.indexOf(cls) !== -1;
  },
   getProviders: function () {
     return [UtilityService, CookieService, CookieModule, CookieOptionsProvider, BaseService, HeaderService, LoadingService,
       { provide: XHRBackend, useClass: MockBackend },
       { provide: ConfigurationService, useClass: ConfigurationMockService },
       { provide: UserService, useClass: UserMockService },
       { provide: AuthenticationService, useClass: AuthenticationMockService },
       {
         // Here we request that configuration loading be done at app-
         // initialization time (prior to rendering)
         provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
         useFactory: (configService: ConfigurationService) =>
           () => configService.loadConfigurationData(),
         deps: [ConfigurationService],
         multi: true
       },
       { provide: 'BASE_URL', useFactory: '', deps: [] }];
  },

  getImports: function () {
    return [FormsModule,
      RouterTestingModule,
      CookieModule.forRoot(),
      HttpClientModule,
      HttpModule];
  }

};
```